# объявление переменных внутри функции postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Была написана функция в sql server, ее надо перенести в postgre,
выдает ошибку синтаксиса на объявлении переменных, подскажите плз как правильно их объявить?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SubmitReview(_paper_id INT, _reviewer_id INT, _score INT)

    RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
....

        DECLARE @mark float =0; 
        DECLARE @Count INT =0; 

...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: А какая ошибка то?

Comment: syntax error at or near "DECLARE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ее надо перенести в postgre

А почему не почитали [документацию](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html)?

> All variables used in a block must be declared in the declarations section of the block.
>
> Все переменные, используемые в блоке, должны объявляться в секции объявлений этого блока.

Вот так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SubmitReview(_paper_id INT, _reviewer_id INT, _score INT)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE 
    mark float; 
    Count INT; 
BEGIN

    mark := 0;
    count := 0;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: спасибо, я читал, не смог найти нужный пример

Answer (score 1):

В PostgreSQL параметры функции не объявляются, лишь указываются их типы данных. Обращение осуществляются по индексу. Также, в блоке DECLARE на них можно задать именованные алиасы для обращения в теле не по индексам, а по этим алиасам.

И декларация переменный осуществляется в соответсвующем блоке, а не в теле.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SubmitReview(INT, INT, INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  _paper_id alias for ;
  _reviewer_id alias for ;
  _score alias for ;
BEGIN
...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Хотя, соврал, объявлять их можно и с именами, но не обязательно. Так что ошибка исключительно в следствии DECLARE в теле.

раздел офф мануала [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)